# Mysql database structure for web application

Tags: mysql, database, structure

I got this schema so far:

```
Advertising Company Table
  advertising_company_id
  name

Placement Table
  placement_id
  name

Advertiser Table
  advertiser_id
  name

Location Table
  location_id
  name

Ads Table
  ad_id
  size
  price
  advertising_company_id
  placement_id
  advertiser_id
  location_id
```

Question 1: Is this schema fine, or should I change anything?

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what your project/client requirements are it's hard to say. But it looks simple enough and will probably serve as a good enough baseline starting point. I would add the following fields to all tables:

```
created DATETIME() [default NOW()]
created_by INT [user ID]
modified DATETIME()
midified_by INT [user ID]
```

Ads Table

```
ad_start_time DATETIME()
ad_end_time DATETIME()
ad_type INT [you might need ad types?]
ad_invoice_id INT
```

Are you tracking pricing info?

Good luck